# Error: Java heap space

Tags: hadoop

In Ubuntu, when I am running the hadoop example :

```
$bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+' 

$echo $HADOOP_HEAPSIZE
2000
```

In log, I am getting the error as :

> INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201303251213_0012_m_000000_2,
>   Status : FAILED
>   **Error: Java heap space** 13/03/25 15:03:43 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :attempt_201303251213_0012_m_000001_2,  Status : FAILED Error:
>   Java heap space13/03/25 15:04:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: #
>   of failed     Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1.
>   LastFailedTask:    task_201303251213_0012_m_000000
>   java.io.IOException: Job failed! at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1265) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep.run(Grep.java:69) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep.main(Grep.java:93)

Let us know what is the problem.

Answer (score 45):

Clearly you have run out of the heap size allotted to Java. So you shall try to increase that.

For that you may execute the following before executing `hadoop` command:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Xmx4096m"
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by adding the following permanent setting in your `mapred-site.xml` file, this file lies in `HADOOP_HOME/conf/` :

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx4096m</value>
</property>
```

This would set your java heap space to 4096 MB (4GB), you may even try it with a lower value first if that works. If that too doesn't work out then increase it more if your machine supports it, if not then move to a machine having more memory and try there. As heap space simply means you don't have enough RAM available for Java.

**UPDATE:** For Hadoop 2+, make the changes in *mapreduce.map.java.opts* instead.

Comment: thanks a lot, this saved the day for me. Clearly this should have been marked as the answer to the question!

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to set final to true in mapred-site.xml for this setting as well (since otherwise it might get overwritten by the configuration in hadoop-env.sh, should there happen to be one)?

Comment: Just an update, for hadoop 2+, change mapreduce.map.java.opts instead.

Answer (score 7):

```
<property>
   <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx4096m</value>
</property>
```

Works for me.

> export HADOOP_OPTS="-Xmx4096m"

doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Using Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.2.0, this worked for me to change the heap size of the local (sequential) java process:

```
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=2900
hadoop jar analytics.jar .....
```

The reason it worked is that /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-config.sh has

```
# check envvars which might override default args
if [ "$HADOOP_HEAPSIZE" != "" ]; then
  #echo "run with heapsize $HADOOP_HEAPSIZE"
  JAVA_HEAP_MAX="-Xmx""$HADOOP_HEAPSIZE""m"
  #echo $JAVA_HEAP_MAX
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add property on mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx2048m</value>
</property>
```

Sometimes it happens another
because it more than virtual memory limit
In this situation,
you must add

```
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
        <value>4.2</value>
</property>
```

on yarn-site.xml

because its default 2.1G sometimes too small.